# What is the statistical model to find probabilities of drawing certain cards in my card game?

Tags: combinatorics

There are four card types. Red, Blue, Green, and Black. From a deck of 20 cards (6 red, 6 blue, 6 green, and 2 black) you randomly draw 6 cards without replacement. I am trying to program a calculator that calculates the probability of drawing 2 reds for instance. How about 4 blues? 6 greens? I would also need to find the probability of drawing combinations such as P(3reds, 1blue, 2green) or P(5blue, 1black). If I have a generic formula I can code it such that different parameters are passed to calculate the probability of each scenario happening. This would greatly help me in designing my card game. Trying to figure out how to give more points for drawing low probability hand in my game. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered by the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](http://www.epixanalytics.com/modelassist/AtRisk/Model_Assist.htm#Distributions/Discrete_distributions/Multivariate_Hypergeometric.htm). Let $D_i$ be the number of cards of color $i$ and let $x_i$ be the desired number of chosen cards, with $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$. Then:

$$P(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\frac{\binom{D_1}{x_1}\binom{D_2}{x_2}\binom{D_3}{x_3}\binom{D_4}{x_4}}{\binom{M}{n}},$$

where $M=D_1+D_2+D_3+D_4$. This can naturally reduce to answer your questions. For example if you're just interested in red, then:

$$P(x_1)=\frac{\binom{D_1}{x_1}\binom{M-D_1}{n-x_1}}{\binom{M}{n}}.$$

Comment: This solves for all combinations thanks. For the "at least 2" kind of problems, do I just calculate all individual probabilities using the provided formula and add them up? or there is a generic formula for those kind of range problems too?

Comment: You can work it out for any case. For 2 the numerator will be $$\binom{D_1}{x_1}\binom{D_2}{x_2}\binom{M-D_1-D_2}{n-x_1-x_2}:$$

Pick $x_1$ objects of color 1, $x_2$ objects of color 2, and the rest from the other colors.

Comment: No I mean something like P(x1 >= 2). Like at least 2 reds. Maybe I'm not using the P notation correctly but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yea in that case there’s no closed form and you have to numerically sum